# How can I store values in an array and reuse it every session in chrome extension storage?

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-storage

I'm trying to make an array with the ids (of the Users) the user clicks on. The function is:

```
$('button').click(function(){
var value = $('this').parents('.username').attr('id')
// How to create array in the chrome storage?

// How can I push the value to an array and create a permanent one?
})
```

Comment: Can you please provide a runnable example?

Comment: Not sure what example do you mean but the code above is the simplified version of mine. I don't really know how to deal with chrome extension functions so I left them blank. :/

Comment: Ok, Thats fine. Can you link the chrome extenstions however in your question?#

Comment: The only thing I'm stuck at is creating an array and adding to it. Sorry, about not providing full info but my extension is running locally and I'm a chrome api newbie.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like:

```
chrome.storage.local.get("myArray", function(dataStored) {  //load your saved array, if it exists
  var workingArray = dataStored.myArray || [];  //if it doesn't exist, create an empty one
  workingArray.push(value);  //add the value just obtained
  chrome.storage.local.set({myArray:workingArray});  //save the array.
});
```

Comment: thanks for the answer I'll try it, but can you explain how line 2 creates a new array if it doesn't exist?

Comment: The variable `workingArray` is assigned `dataStore.myArray` if it exists, or an empty array `[ ]` if `dataStore.myArray` doesn't exist. It is equivalent to `if (dataStore.myArray) { workingArray = dataStore.myArray;} else { workingArray = [ ];}`